# Call Facebook login and then press home button to get back

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the following problem, I would like to know if there is something implemented by facebook or if you know a workflow to avoid this issue.

Basically I use facebook SDK to login, the app send me to the browser, and instead of clicking `cancel` or `Accept/OK`, I click home button and get back to the app.
In that case I don't receive any callback from facebook SDK.

Also, facebook have a delay when you click `cancel` or `ok` button, so when you get back to the app you don't know exactly if you are going to receive the callback or not by 2-3 seconds aprox.

My current solution is giving a delay of 3-4 seconds and check if you are already connected or not, and show the buttons again if you are not connected. It's a really bad approach, but I can't find something better for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to handle this in your AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive` method:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{        
    // Handles activation with regards to returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

Docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/#handleDidBecomeActive

and

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Comment: thanks, I solved my problem that was related with another issue. the app didn't call applicationDidBecomeActive because is using another schema, not a simple UIView for iOS.